# Is the noise in current measurements additive to device signal?

Tags: noise, current-measurement, resistivity

I am a chemical engineer, not an electrical engineer, so hopefully this can be explained to me with my still developing knowledge on the matter.

I have been tasked with running current measurements to get the bulk resistivity of polymer samples, we have a Keithley 6514B electrometer and the 8009 resistivity fixture for it. Our set up is getting a fair amount of noise. I believe this is from the environmental chamber we have the samples in. I am working to get better isolation of the DUT, but in the meantime, I am wondering if the data I have collected is any good.

Is the noise in these measurements additive to the signal once voltage is applied, like does it actually offset the signal at all, or is it just making the 0V reading before test more unfocused in its resolution of the current value?

Comment: Can you give us a diagram of your set up? A graph of the noise your seeing? Both of these would help us understand the issues

Comment: If the noise is purely electrical, and originating from outside the machine, it is very likely to be AC, therefore if you average for a long time it should average to zero. You should obtain a few samples with known resistivity, and you can test this.

Comment: You may be able to eliminate something like mains-frequency noise by post-processing iff the input is not distorting too much (eg. clipping).